# Event emitter with conditions

Tags: javascript, object, events

I've created an event emitter class. It works properly. Let me tell you how:

This is the class:

```
class EventEmitter{

    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }

    on(eventName,callback) {
        if(this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName].push(callback);
        } else {
            this.events[eventName] = [callback]; 
        }
    }

    trigger(eventName, ...rest) {
        if(this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName].forEach(cb => {
                cb.apply(null,rest); 
            });
        }
    }
 }
```

With this class i can listen to certain events. Like so :

```
 const ee = new EventEmitter();
 ee.on('change', (aa) => {
     console.log(aa);
 });
```

Then i can trigger it with the trigger method

```
 ee.trigger('change','Argument');
```

Now i want to listen to events with certain conditions.

for example :

```
 ee.on({'change': 'barack the boss'}, (aa) => {
     console.log(aa);
 });
```

The above bit of code should only execute when trigger looks like this:

```
 //wont run
 ee.trigger('change','barack is no boss');
//will run
 ee.trigger('change','barack the boss');
```

I wonder how to do this. I am not asking you to write my code, I would like an example or a step in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Whole code:

```
class EventEmitter{

    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }

    on(eventName,callback) {
        if(this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName].push(callback);
        } else {
            this.events[eventName] = [callback]; 
        }
    }

    trigger(eventName, ...rest) {
        if(this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName].forEach(cb => {
                cb.apply(null,rest); 
            });
        }
    }
 }

//events has been created and is currently an empty object
 const ee = new EventEmitter();

//even has been created, this event has a function which will be executed when event is triggered
 ee.on({'change': 'barack the boss'}, (aa) => {
     console.log(aa);
 });

 //wont run
 ee.trigger('change','barack is no boss');
//will run
 ee.trigger('change','barack the boss');
```

Comment: Quick question, would these both be valid triggers for you: `ee.trigger('change','barack the boss')`, `ee.trigger('change','barack the boss', someArgumentForTheListeners)`

Comment: @Axel the last one would be good. It could use the second to check the condition and the last one for the listener

Comment: Not sure I've got the point but you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/3qmd4h12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use [Object.Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on the `.on()` event register. This would allow you to iterate trough the object passed (which at the same time would give you the ability to register multiple events in a single call).

With `Object.Keys` you can iterate trough the argument object as if it were an array. Then you can register the the value of the key as a condition when triggering the event.